# Spring JMS Consumer Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I have created a JMS broker with Apache ActiveMQ and a simple application that enqueues messages ok.

I would like to create another simple application that dequeues those messages asynchronously using an MDP. Here's an example of what I have so far:

**Consumer POJO**

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyMessageListener.class);

  public void onMessage(Message message) {
   try {
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
    LOG.info("Consumed message: " + msg.getText());
   } catch (JMSException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
}
```

**And here's the relevant bits of my Spring XML configuration file**

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616 />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleMessageListener"
class="main.SimpleMessageListener">

<jms:listener-container
container-type="default"
connection-factory="connectionFactory"
acknowledge="auto">
<jms:listener destination="testqueue"
ref="simpleMessageListener" method="onMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

Now presumably I need a main method, but given the listener calls the onMessage method asynchronously when a message arrives on the queue, I am not sure how to code this up:

```
public class App {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
  // what do I need here?
  //MyMessageListener msglistener ?
  }
}
```

Thank-you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the Spring application context, e.g. instantiate a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation